# Validation error while upgrading from SQL server 2008R2 SP3 to SQL server 2016SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I am going to qualifying `MS-SQL server 2016`(**clean and upgrade both**) for my application. But when I try to upgrade form `SQL server 2008R2 SP3` to `SQL server 2016SP1` , It gives me an error saying `validation error as "There are no features selected for upgrade"` .
Is there any patch that I have to apply on `SQL 2008` before upgrading to `SQL 2016` ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated..

Comment: upgrade from 2008R2 to 2016? what and how are you upgrading exactly? a single database? It sound like you think you can simply upgrade the SQL server versions, but that's not possible, you can install 2 versions side by side and migrate databases across. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: this is single database which I am trying to upgrade from sql 2008 to sql 2016. Actually I have successfully done upgrade from SQL 2014 to SQL 2016

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your 2008 R2 instance is not 32-bit as this would prevent you from upgrading in this way.

If you are unsure, run this and look at the output.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```